# Consistency shading_Conditional formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I have developed a code to format cells using a VBA code based on consistency of formulas. The issue however is that the code provides static formatting and I need it to be converted to static formatting. Another thing is that I have used pattern shading instead of cell highlights as I have another macro that uses conditional fill.

Can someone help me out to modify the code so that this picks pattern shading and uses conditional formatting to provide pattern shading? Any help with be appreciated!!

Find my code below -

```
Sub ShadeFnew()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Call FormulaShading
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Sub FormulaShading(Optional ApplyIsError As Boolean = False, Optional RemoveIsError As Boolean = False)

Dim oneCell As Range
Dim CellOnLeft As Range
Dim CellOnTop As Range
Dim ContantCommentAdded As Boolean
Dim ColShift As Long
Dim RowShift As Long
Dim usedRange As Range
Dim CurrSheet As String
Dim sh As Variant
Dim SheetNames() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim ReadyForExit As Boolean
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim Rng As Range


i = 0
EmptyColCount = 0
EmptyRowCount = 0
'ContantCommentAdded = False

ReadyForExit = False
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Windows(1).SelectedSheets
ReDim Preserve SheetNames(i)
SheetNames(i) = sh.Name
i = i + 1
Next
CurrSheet = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name
'Call RemoveFormulaShade

For j = 0 To UBound(SheetNames)
Sheets(SheetNames(j)).Activate
Sheets(SheetNames(j)).Select
If Selection.Rows.Count > 1 Or Selection.Columns.Count > 1 Then
Set usedRange = Selection
ReadyForExit = True
Else
Set Rng = ActiveSheet.usedRange
On Error Resume Next
LastColumn = Rng.Find(What:="*", After:=Rng.Cells(1), Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Column
LastRow = Rng.Find(What:="*", After:=Rng.Cells(1), Lookat:=xlPart, LookIn:=xlFormulas, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, MatchCase:=False).Row
If Err.Number > 0 Then
On Error GoTo 0
GoTo NextSheet:
End If
Set usedRange = Range(Cells(ActiveSheet.usedRange.Rows(1).Row, ActiveSheet.usedRange.Columns(1).Column), Cells(LastRow, LastColumn))
End If
'Debug.Print "Used Range : " & ActiveSheet.usedRange.Address
'Debug.Print "Actual Range : " & usedRange.Address

If ApplyIsError Then

On Error Resume Next
If RemoveIsError Then

Else
Set usedRange = Nothing
If Selection.Rows.Count > 1 Or Selection.Columns.Count > 1 Then
Set usedRange = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
Else

Set usedRange = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
End If
End If

If usedRange Is Nothing Then GoTo NextSheet
On Error GoTo 0
For Each oneCell In usedRange
If oneCell.HasFormula Then

fnApplyIsError oneCell, RemoveIsError

End If
Next
Else

For Each oneCell In usedRange

If oneCell.Column > 1 Then
Set CellOnLeft = Cells(oneCell.Row, oneCell.Column - 1)
Else
Set CellOnLeft = oneCell
End If

If oneCell.Row > 1 Then
Set CellOnTop = Cells(oneCell.Row - 1, oneCell.Column)
Else
Set CellOnTop = oneCell
End If
ContantCommentAdded = False


Dim flag As Boolean
flag = False

If oneCell.HasFormula = False Then
GoTo NextIteration:
End If

'Debug.Print oneCell.Address
If oneCell.Column > 2 And ((Trim(CStr(CellOnLeft.Value)) <> "" And CellOnLeft.HasFormula = False) Or Trim(CStr(CellOnLeft.Value)) = "") Then
'If CellOnLeft.Comment Is Nothing Then
' CellOnLeft.AddComment ("Constant in a formula range")
' ContantCommentAdded = True
'Else
' If InStr(CellOnLeft.Comment.Text, "Constant in a formula range") > 0 Then
' CellOnLeft.Comment.Text CellOnLeft.Comment.Text & vbCrLf & "Constant in a formula range", 1
' ContantCommentAdded = True
' End If
'End If
'CellOnLeft.Comment.Creator "ABCD"
i = 2

While i <= 6 And (oneCell.Column - i > 0) And flag = False
If Cells(oneCell.Row, oneCell.Column - i).HasFormula Then
Set CellOnLeft = Cells(oneCell.Row, oneCell.Column - i)
flag = True
End If
i = i + 1
Wend
End If
flag = False
If oneCell.Row > 2 And ((Trim(CStr(CellOnTop.Value)) <> "" And CellOnTop.HasFormula = False) Or Trim(CStr(CellOnTop.Value)) = "") Then
'If CellOnTop.Comment Is Nothing Then
' CellOnTop.AddComment ("Constant in a formula range")
'Else
' If ContantCommentAdded = False Then
' CellOnTop.Comment.Text CellOnTop.Comment.Text & vbCrLf & "Constant in a formula range", 1
' End If
'End If
'CellOnTop.Comment.Creator "ABCD"
'Set CellOnTop = Cells(oneCell.Row - 2, oneCell.Column)
i = 2
While i <= 6 And (oneCell.Row - i > 0) And flag = False
If Cells(oneCell.Row - i, oneCell.Column).HasFormula Then
Set CellOnTop = Cells(oneCell.Row - i, oneCell.Column)
flag = True
End If
i = i + 1
Wend

End If




If CellOnLeft.FormulaR1C1 <> oneCell.FormulaR1C1 And CellOnTop.FormulaR1C1 <> oneCell.FormulaR1C1 Then
If oneCell.HasFormula And Trim(CStr(CellOnLeft.Value)) <> "" And Trim(CStr(CellOnTop.Value)) <> "" And CellOnLeft.HasFormula And CellOnTop.HasFormula Then

ShadeCell oneCell, "G"

GoTo NextIteration:
Else

ShadeCell oneCell, "G"

GoTo NextIteration:
End If
End If

If CellOnTop.FormulaR1C1 <> oneCell.FormulaR1C1 And oneCell.Column = 1 Then


ShadeCell oneCell, "G"

GoTo NextIteration:
End If


If CellOnLeft.FormulaR1C1 <> oneCell.FormulaR1C1 And oneCell.Row = 1 Then

ShadeCell oneCell, "G"

GoTo NextIteration:
End If

If CellOnLeft.FormulaR1C1 = oneCell.FormulaR1C1 And CellOnLeft.HasFormula And oneCell.Column And oneCell.Column > 1 Then

ShadeCell oneCell, "H"

GoTo NextIteration:
End If

If CellOnTop.FormulaR1C1 = oneCell.FormulaR1C1 And CellOnTop.HasFormula And oneCell.Row > 1 Then

ShadeCell oneCell, "V"

GoTo NextIteration:
End If

If oneCell.Row = 1 And oneCell.Column = 1 And oneCell.HasFormula Then
ShadeCell oneCell, "G"
GoTo NextIteration:
End If

NextIteration:

If Not oneCell Is Nothing Then

If IsError(oneCell.Value) Then

ShadeCell oneCell, "E"

End If
End If
Next
If ReadyForExit Then
Exit For
End If
End If
NextSheet:
Next j
Sheets(CurrSheet).Activate
End Sub

Sub ShadeCell(oneCell As Range, typ As String)
Dim theColor

theColor = oneCell.Interior.ColorIndex
If theColor = -4142 Then
theColor = xlAutomatic
End If

Select Case (typ)
Case "H": 'horizontal
With oneCell.Interior
.Pattern = xlLightHorizontal
.PatternColor = 16776960
.ColorIndex = theColor
.TintAndShade = 0
.PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
Case "V": 'Vertical
With oneCell.Interior
.Pattern = xlLightVertical
.PatternColor = 16776960
.ColorIndex = theColor
.TintAndShade = 0
.PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
Case "G": 'Grid
With oneCell.Interior
.Pattern = xlGrid
.PatternColor = 16776960
.ColorIndex = theColor
.TintAndShade = 0
.PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
Case "C": 'Cross Grid or checker
With oneCell.Interior
.Pattern = xlChecker
.PatternColor = 16776960
.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
.TintAndShade = 0
.PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
Case "U": 'Unshade
'MsgBox "Here"
If oneCell.Interior.ColorIndex = -4105 Then
theColor = xlNone
End If
If oneCell.Interior.ColorIndex = -4142 Then
theColor = xlNone
End If
With oneCell.Interior
.Pattern = xlNone
.PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
.ColorIndex = theColor
.TintAndShade = 0
.PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
If Not (oneCell.Comment Is Nothing) Then
If oneCell.Comment.text = "Error" Then
oneCell.Comment.Delete
End If
End If

Case "E": 'Error
With oneCell.Interior
.Pattern = xlLightUp
.PatternThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
.TintAndShade = 0
.PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
If oneCell.Comment Is Nothing Then
On Error Resume Next
oneCell.AddComment ("Error")
On Error GoTo 0
End If
End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I am bad with conditional formatting codes and hence thought to seek help from the community. Thanks in advance for the help!! :)

Comment: What do you mean by "consistent" formulas? When is a formula consistent and when not?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. For reference, place some consistent formulas and non consistent formulas row wise and column wise on a sheet and try running the macro, you will be able to understand what I mean.